# I am looking for an event when the combobox filling items is finished, dojo1.8

Tags: dojo

Hi I am looking for an event for Combobox where it is finished with filling items.
Is it onSearch event? Would appreciate if there's an example.

During  the filling of the combobox with items, it has to be on standby.
When it is completed, then standby is removed.

```
require(['dojox/widget/Standby',dijit/form/Button  'dojo/domReady!']
function(Standby, Button)
{
    var pause = new Standby({target:"main_bContainer"});
    document.body.appendChild(pause.domNode);
    pause.startup();

    var buttonX = new button
    ({
      .... button creation...
    });

    var combox1 = new comboBox
    ({
        .... combobox  creation...
        onSearch(results, query, options)???
        pause.hide();
    });

    on(buttonX, 'change'...)
    {
     ....pause.show();
     .... start querying from database and fill combobox with items here
    }

 });
```

See onSearch(results, query, options)???
Would appreciate for help.
Clement

Comment: I am sorry i fail to see your problem, when you get values from databse are you getting them one by one or a blob ?? if a blob you shouldn't have problem with stoping the standby after getting the blob and inserting in the itemfilewritestore. am I missing somehting

Comment: pause.show() came into play, when the query started on database and begin filling retrieved in the combobox. Once it is finished, then the pause.hide() is executed. I hope i have  made it simple here to be understood.

Comment: It is so simple that i can't understand where is your problem when you finish and insert the value in the dropdown run the pause.hide()

Comment: The question I asked, is what kind of event of the filled Combobox Select, that will activate standby.hide?